# Java objects and classes used in another class

Tags: java, python

I am having some trouble porting a Java project using Python. Basically what I don't understand, is what line 4 does. Dice is a class defined somewhere else. I am more than sure that it doesn't create an object or instance from the Dice class. Is it just allocating memory for later creation? I really have no clue.

### Code in question:

```
1 public class Move {
2
3  // the dice used for this move
4  protected Dice dice;
5  // the set of movements used to perform this move, in this order
6  protected Movement[] movements;
7  .....}
```

P.S: stackoverflow has such a great community! So far all my problems could be solved by checking here. But now I am lost and had to finally create an account ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement declares a class member. Class members are different for local objects/variables because they are accessible from the whole class. In this case, it defines a protected object of type `Dice` named `dice`.

The statement does not actually create a `Dice` object; it merely states that it exists. If you are to use it, you can instantiate it in a method. For example:

```
public class Move {
    protected Dice dice;
    ...
    public void someMethod() {
        dice = new Dice();
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help! Indeed, good questions and answers make Stack Overflow a great community :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it just allocate the memory for a `Dice` object as a protected property of your class `Move`.

Edit : it's not really memory allocation until the object is not clearly assigned. It's more likely defining a relation : `Move` object is composed of a protected `Dice` object.

Comment: Thank you, that was quick. So I can ignore that in python and just create my `Dice` object whenever I need it later on.

Comment: Yes, you can. However, I recommand you to create a `dice` instance variable in the `__init__` method, because of some PEP recommanding it. But this is not directly related to the question.

Answer (score 1):

For `protected Dice dice;` it's like a declaration of a place holder. It's only a definition. You says: Here's my class, and I will put maybe a Dice instance there, named 'dice'.

Same thing for `protected Movement[] movements;`

Under the hood, it define a variable that contain a pointer. That pointer will eventually contain a value (a memory location) that contains the instance of the object (like a Dice object)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!